# how to do capture stdout and stderr on bash on OS X

Tags: bash, macos

I have some bash scripts that captures both stdout and stderr and appends this to  file.

`echo asdf &>>asdf`

This works nicely on my ubuntubox but is apparently this is not allowed on osx.

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

Is there an easy workaround?

Thanks

Comment: try `>> "log_file" 2>&1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo asdf >> log_file_name 2>&1
```